# onClick loading per instance using map

Tags: reactjs

`loading` is being set and passed into props but the loader fires on all instances of `item` when `onClick` is pressed on any button. How do I only have the loader run on the button that is pressed?

```
List.map((item, i) => {
  return(
<Button onClick={(e) => !props.loading && e.stopPropagation()}>
  Save {props.loading && (<CircularProgress/>)}
</Button>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a boolean variable for loading in the parent component, you must use an array of Ids to render loading in each button. Here is an example:
You can check this code in the code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-sun-kmwb24?file=/src/App.js:0-582).

```
import "./styles.css";
import CircularProgress from "@mui/material/CircularProgress";
import { useState } from "react";

const items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];

export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {items.map((item) => (
        <button
          key={item}
          id={item}
          onClick={(e) => {
            setLoading([...loading, e.target.id]);
          }}
        >
          {loading.includes(item) ? <CircularProgress /> : item}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

this is a simple example that I have implemented. If the user clicks on a button, only that button will render a loading spinner. You can implement it in many ways. You can also add logic to remove loading if the user clicks on the loading button by checking whether the item exists in the state. If it is, You can simply remove it from the loading list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a way to get a handle on the unique item in the loop.  Lets say the  List is an array of items in the shape of [{ id: 1, name: "one"},{ id: 2, name: "Two"}]

Insead of props.loading, you need to specfy the ID in loading, not a boolean.

So for example in your component

Then in your map:

> Save {props.loading === item.id && ()}

Comment: How do I specify ID in loading?

Comment: Can you paste the component that uses this list?

Comment: Here it is in a codepen since the real use case is rather involved: https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/OJoZzxe The actual name of `List` is `taxList`

Answer (score 0):

As might have realised the issue is that you are using the same prop for all the buttons.

One way to avoid this is changing the loading prop type from boolean to an unique identifier (so you know which list item is loading). Assuming you set the loading on click and your item has an unique id you could do something like:

```
  List.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <Button
        onClick={(e) => {
          if (props.loading === item.id) return // or props.loading === index or any unique identifier
          e.stopPropagation()
          prop.setLoading(item.id) // or prop.setLoading(index) or any unique identifier
        }}
      >
        Save {props.loading === item.id && <CircularProgress />} // or props.loading === index or any unique identifier
      </Button>
    )
});
```

Please note that you can call the `setLoading` outside of this function. This is only for demonstration purposes. You can call it where you need and where it makes more sense.

You can also use the any other unique identifier instead of `id` (as shown in the comments).

But for the index solution, if your list is filtrable or the `index` of one element might change for any reason (for example: list might trim or an element might be added/removed) is it not recommended to use `index` prop since it might cause unexpected behaviour  (you would need to recalculate the loading prop each time an element changes it's index). So I would suggest any other unique identifier from List array if possible.